# Controlling a specific process id in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, process, child-process, command-line-interface

I'm developing a node application that allows a client to control a program running on the server. The program must always be running on its own terminal window. Ideal scenario is outlined as follows:

client clicks a button -> command is run in terminal running program-> program does something

I'm not too experienced with node but I know that I can run command line scripts using the ChildProcess event emitter. The issue I'm having is how do I tell node to run a command on a particular process (i.e. the one running the program I'm trying to manipulate). Is there a way to execute commands on a specific process id? Is there a way to detect all current processes and their id's?

Any suggestions or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a child process, you can assign it to a variable so that you can reference it later. In this instance, you may want to add it to an object or array so that you can reference a group of running processes.

You can refer to the documentation for [spawn](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) or [exec](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) for examples.

One way to send commands to a created child process is using [signals](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_kill_signal), such as `child.kill('SIGSOMETHING');`

For example:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

function spawnChild() {
  var cmd = spawn('cmd', ['-p1', 'param']);

  cmd.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('stdout: ' + data);
  });

  cmd.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    console.log('stderr: ' + data);
  });

  cmd.on('close', function (code) {
    console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
  });

  // Save a reference to this child
  children.push(cmd);
}

// Spawn 5 children
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  spawnChild();
}

// Send a signal after 5 seconds
setTimeout(function(){
  for (var i in children) {
    var child = children[i];
    console.log('Sending signal to child with PID: ' + child.pid);
    child.kill('SIGSOMETHING');
  }
}, 5000);
```